# BigQuery View is not working if I used BigQuery Plugin

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I've been used bigquery plugin under the source category. When I used bigquery View, Pipeline through an error of not allowed View. Also If I used the permanent table in which repeatable columns have existed, then it also through an error of unsupported mode 'repeated' while retrieving its schema. Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery source exports the data from the table into temporary GCS buckets and then read it in the pipeline. Since BigQuery VIEWs cannot be exported (please see limitations here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views), pipeline fails.

Also currently BigQuery source does not support repeatable column. The work is currently in progress - https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15256. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yep. That's helpful.